# How to get the call back from app update popup whether user select CANCEL or INSTALL

Tags: android

[image: app update OS popup]My app is not available in play store. I am updating the app(APK) from local storage. I want do some logic based on whether user select CANCEL or INSTALL.

```
 Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(appUpdate), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivityForResult(promptInstall, 12346);

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 12346){
            Toast.makeText(RootActivity.this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                Toast.makeText(RootActivity.this, "RESULT_OK ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(RootActivity.this, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no way you can achieve that through onActivityResult. One way - you can have some static method in your application class that can return your current app version (so you can compare it with version you keep in for example SharedPreferences). Other way -  you can keep a boolean variable (false by default) in activity and put true in it when user press install button of your activity and every time when user goes to Android install dialog window and press cancel(onDestroy does not call this way) you return to your last ativity where onResume call fires, so you can check value of your boolean variable - that works just fine if your launch activity is different with your InstalUpdateActivity.